# After I deleted a directory, it always prompts "shell-init error retrieving current directory getcwd solve" when log on bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know that changing to an existing directory may solve the problem. But the thing is that what I deleted *was not the home directory*. I simply deleted the directory `/home/desktop/zeno`, which was created by root, and the `$HOME` variable is `/home/zeno`. Also took a look at `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and even `/etc/profile`, but found no commands asking to initialize bash at `/home/desktop/zeno`. What should be examined next? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you say "log on", is that actually logging on like through ssh or after a reboot, or are you just opening a new xterm?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes, I mean simply open the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

When opening a new shell or xterm, it's started in the working directory of the process that started it.

If you e.g. `cd /proc && xterm`, the new terminal will place you in `/proc`.

Whatever's starting your terminal had positioned itself in `/home/desktop/zeno`, and now all the terminals are trying to start there. If you make that process change directory (by rebooting, for example), the terminals will start in a directory that exists and you will no longer get this error.

Comment: Thanks! The error really went away after restarting the system.